# implementing Queue using web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

i want to create a Queue with web service.
and this is my code :

```
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    Queue myQueue = new Queue();

    [WebMethod]
    public void push(int item)
    {
        if (myQueue == null)
            myQueue = new Queue();
        myQueue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public int pop()
    {
        if (myQueue != null)
        {
            if (myQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                return (int)myQueue.Dequeue();
            }

        }

            return -1;


    }
}
```

the push() method works fine,but when i call pop() for retrieving data, it always returns -1
what is my code problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `myQueue` as `static`. (`static Queue myQueue = new Queue();`) since it seems that  a new instance of `Service1` is created with every call.

Answer (score 1):

As I4V said, static does the job, but make sure to protect against simultaneous callers.  No need to manually instantiate myQueue within push, as the declaration guarantees an instance is ready for use.

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    static Queue myQueue = new Queue();

    [WebMethod]
    public void push(int item)
    {
        lock(myQueue)
        {
            myQueue.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public int pop()
    {
        lock(myQueue)
        {
            if (myQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                return (int)myQueue.Dequeue();
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider using a Generic Queue, so you don't have to keep casting.  It's safer, and faster.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

```
// before class declaration
using System.Collections.Generic;

// replaces myQueue declaration
static Queue<int> myQueue = new Queue<int>();

// later, in pop - myQueue already returns ints, so no casting needed
return myQueue.Dequeue();
```